# Notification when I'm near a stored location

Tags: android, gps, notifications, location, flashlight

I currently write on an app which should give me information about the places in my area. I've already built a function that indicates how far a user is away from a location (via GPS).

Now I want that the user gets an information at a certain distance to a place (eg 20 meters).

For that I have the following questions:

1. How can I get that the app continues in the background (including GPS) and checks the current distance to a place?
2. How can I find / notify the user when he/she is in the vicinity of a place and the app itself is only running in the background (eg when the screen is locked). I would have preferred that the LED on the device lights / the phone vibrate briefly and the information can be seen, such as in a text message.

Even now, many thanks for your help,

a small programmer who is still at the very beginning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a [Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) which runs in the background and set a [ProximityAlert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert(double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) to trigger a [Pending Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) when user enters your specific area.

Comment: @hungry7, here are a few examples:
 - [Part 1 (also see Part 2 & 3)– Developing Proximity Alerts](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/07/part-1-developing-proximity-alerts-for-mobile-applications-using-the-android-platform/)
 - [Android Proximity Alert Tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html)